# Python code for starting the app from the beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

I need help with adding a code after the `elif answer == "y":` that starts the app again from the beginning

```
answer = input("Run again? (y/n): ")
import sys
if answer == "n":
    print("Goodbye.")
    sys.exit   
elif answer == "y":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

status = True
while(status):
    answer = input("Run again? (y/n): ")
    if answer == "n":
        status = False   
    elif answer == "y":
        status = True
print("Goodbye.")
sys.exit
```

Comment: Tip: `status = answer == 'y'`

Comment: What's the benefit of `while(status):` as opposed to `while status:` ?

Comment: @MichaelMaggs There is no benefit. They should not be there. If you use any good editor, you will typically get a warning to remove those kinds of redundant parentheses.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work smoothly, when I click no it exits the program without saying "Good Bye" but when I say Yes it says "Good Bye" and restarts just the last part "Run again? (y/n):". Also, I begin learning Python so if you could me how 'status' and 'while' work I would be grateful since I couldn't get it.